# Degree of algebraic element over a field and a galois extension

Tags: galois-theory

> **The question** Is the proposition 1 correct? If it is, how can we prove it in general?

> **Proposition 1** Suppose that $E$ is a Galois extension of $F$ and $f(x) \in E[x]$ be a monic irreducible polynomial over $E$. Let $G$ be the Galois group of $E$ over $F$. The the product of the orbit of the action by $G$ of $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial over $F$.

Note that the Galois group act on polynomials by acting on the coefficients.
I was trying to answer a question from a student. He ask me the proof of the follownig proposition. I don't know where it had come from and/or if it is a correct proposition.

> **Proposition 2** Let $F \le E \le L$ be a tower of field extension where $E$ is a Galois extension over $F$. Let $\alpha \in L$ be algebraic over $E$. Let $m$ be the degree of $\alpha$ over $E$ and $n$ be the degree of $\alpha$ over $F$. Then $m|n$.

To prove proposition 2, I have argued as follows.

> (Suggested proof of proposition 2) Let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $E$. Let $g(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$. (**Suspected**) Then the product of the elements of orbit of $f(x)$, say $h(x)$ divides $g(x)$ and irreducibility of $g(x)$ guarantees that $g(x) = h(x)$ (up to constant). Therefore the degree of $\alpha$ over $F$ which is the degree of $g(x)$ is a multiple of the degree of $f(x)$, that is the degree of $\alpha$ over $E$.

After that, I have come up with proposition 1 which looks somewhat useful. At my opinion the proof of propositin 1 may go in exactly same way with that of proposition 2.

But I have a point which is unclear. See the sentence beginning with (**Suspected**). If $F$ were perfect, then everything would be perfect. However, is the argument applicable to even if $\alpha$ is inseparable element over $E$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1.

- Note that it fails with $f= ix-i \in E= \Bbb{Q}(i), F=\Bbb{Q}$. You need $f$ to be monic.
- $E/F$ is a Galois extension, $f\in E[x]$ is monic irreducible, $a$ is a root, $h$ is the monic $F$-minimal polynomial of $a$.

  $h=fg$ with $g\in E[x]$.
- For each $\sigma\in G=Gal(E/F)$ we have $h=h^\sigma=f^\sigma g^\sigma$.

  ($f^\sigma$ means applying the automorphism to the coefficients of the polynomial)
- Each $f^\sigma$ is irreducible over $E$.
- $u=\prod_{s\in \{ f^\sigma, \sigma\in G\}} s$ divides $h$.
- $u\in E^G[x]=F[x]$ so we must have $h=u$.

Comment: For the first dot, I mean equal up to constant. I guess one can note ot in the context. Now I will edite it.